# How to LabelEncode input same as that of .pkl file?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Suppose I encoded my dataset to create a machine learning model using : -

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('crop_production.csv')
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
dataset = dataset.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

And I saved this model as .pkl file.

Now I want to call

```
t = le_new.fit_transform(['Andaman and Nicobar Islands','NICOBARS',2000,'Kharif','Arecanut',1254])
# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict([t])
```

How can I achieve this in flask, So that when I use `LabelEconder` it encodes same as of `le`

Example -

`le` encodes `t` as `0  427 3   1   2   2026`

So `le_new` should also encode it like this only to predict accurately

Comment: Why not load the pkl file back and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Well what we can do instead of LabelEncoding it is :-

dataset = pd.read_csv('crop_production.csv')

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Replace categorical data with one-hot encoded data
features_df = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=['State_Name', 'District_Name' , 'Season', 'Crop'])
X = features_df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = features_df.iloc[:, -1].values
```